# Session expires very early as compared to session time out

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session

I built a website in which I am using for authentication for login. There is a default session expiration time which is 20 minutes. But my application logs out (session expires) very early. About just after 2 minutes of inactivity. Please can anyone help me, what may be the issue?

Comment: Maybe your application pool recycles too soon (e.g. because of heavy memory usage)?

Comment: Can you show how you have configured session timeout in web.config?

Comment: <sessionState timeout="70" mode = "InProc"></sessionState>

Comment: when i saw timeout of session, its showing there 70minutes, but expire very early

Comment: Authentication may use a timeout different from Session: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: yes, i have looked this link, thanks, my problem is of session, which is lost very early

Comment: Are you on a server farm? With InProc, your session will be lost if your user connects to a different server.